# Possible bug in last activity display

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Go to the view where the [questions with most activity and interest in this month](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month) are displayed.
At the bottom right corner of every question it shows something like:

> `2h ago User Name`

I assume this is the time of the last modification and the user who modified the question.

The second question in the list is closed for quite a while now, but it shows

> `2h ago  some user`

and this keeps changing.

How can this happen when the question is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People can still edit existing answers... I expect this is what happened to bump this.

Sure enough, glancing at the recent history of the user attributed on the "hottest questions" page:

```
2h revised  What is the worst programming language you ever worked with?
            deleted 65 characters in body
```