# Last activity on question shows modified by user who did not ask or answer

Tags: support, user-interface, recent-activity

[Related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/possible-bug-in-last-activity-display) [have been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54867/how-is-this-user-causing-activity).

[image: soulless oval image]

- The [revision page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4759565/revisions) has no sign of the user sharth
- The [user's activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47453/sharth?tab=activity) also does not have any sign of related activity

I would like to know why the user's name is associated with the question. At least why their display name shows up as having modified the question timeline activity.

Possible reason that I can think of is that, [the user answered and then deleted the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54867/how-is-this-user-causing-activity/54869#54869).

Is this the reason?

Is there a way (for normal users), to look for such details, other than looking at the user activity and the question's revision history.

Comment: the same thing happened to me as [well](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1827/what-does-the-name-shown-beside-the-question-infer/1828?noredirect=1#comment3119_1828).Although this is a minute issue but still the last activity should have been updated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This person posted an answer and then deleted it.  There is no way for a non-10k to see this activity though.  You are forced to make the only reasonable assumption - There is a ghost on SO bumping questions!!!

For reference, here is a link to the ghost answer (10k):

[Differences between webapp and web.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759565/differences-between-webapp-and-web-py/4759719#4759719)

Comment: No ghosts in the databases then.