# Phantom activity on question

Tags: support, recent-activity, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect last activity user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75828/incorrect-last-activity-user)

As of right now, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860882/how-do-i-prevent-accessviolationexception-when-returning-a-string-from-c-to-c) does not appear to have any answers, comments, etc.  This is somewhat normal for questions I ask.  However, when I go to [my user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239394/andrew), the last activity shown on that question is by [Jimbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35589/jimbo).  If this user has an answer, I'd love to read it!  However, I see nothing on the actual question.  Was there a deleted answer or something?

Comment: @Adam Davis Thanks, got it, and I think I see why he deleted it (it doesn't quite answer the question).

Answer (score 0):

Jimbo answered your question about 20 minutes after you asked it, then deleted it about a minute later. Stack Overflow caches post activity stats, and it'll take a little bit to catch up to reality.