# Inconsistent view of featured question

Tags: bug, question-lists

Below is three parts of three screenshots of [the Salesforce Stack Exchange site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour), taken in rapid succession. One of them says that the question was edited 4 hours ago, by someone not being the author, and one of them says it was edited 18 hours ago by the author. What is the truth?

Featured questions list first view:

> [image: Featured questions list first view]

Featured questions list second view:

> [image: Featured questions list second view]

Part of question detail:

> [image: Part of question detail]

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about. I have a *hunch* as to what the issue is, but I can't confirm it without having 10k+ reputation on Salesforce. I believe you'll get a better response if you ask on Salesforce Meta.

Comment: Obviously there was a deleted answer, but that doesn't explain the difference in the view. @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog

Comment: @PatrickHofman You say "obviously", but to me it is far from obvious. How did you deduce that there was a deleted answer?

Comment: Experience @SanderdeJong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

I believe that there was a deleted answer by some user 4 hours ago. That might be the reason for showing 'modified'.

For change in view, there is nothing wrong.

Featured questions when viewed [directly from homepage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) i.e., `salesforce.stackexchange.com/tab=featured` show in the format shown in first image. It shows only the author of the question and when the question is asked.

When you click on [featured tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) when seen from `salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured`, it shows in the view as shown in the second image. It shows recent activity of the question.

It is same for all the Stack Exchange sites. It was reproduced on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour), [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Questions on *Questions* pages (such as /questions or [/search](/search?tab=relevance&q=search) etc., basically any list of questions that isn't the homepage) always show the original post date *unless* you click on the "active" tab.

Questions on the homepage however always show the last "active" date, which is (I believe) anything listed in the answer to [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/307988)

So the "Featured" tab of the homepage and the "Featured" tab of the Questions page will show you a different timestamp...

As for the "modified 4 hours ago", without seeing the question (and having sufficient privileges) I can't say for certain, but that usually indicates a now-deleted answer (See e.g. [Last activity on question shows modified by user who did not ask or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75828/307988)).

Comment: 25 seconds apart. :D